# Privileges at/after 1K not appearing in Achievements dialog?

Tags: discussion, notifications, privileges, achievements-dialog

Today I exactly reached and then passed 1K reputation on [EL&U.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).  Nothing about this was listed in my Achievements Dialogue (upper left corner) as seemed to be the case for other achievements at lower levels on that and other sites.  The change was noted on the [EL&U Privileges page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).
Are notifications not given beyond a certain point, by design?
If so, that's fine.  If not, then this is a bug; I mention it for the possibility of the latter.

Comment: It's by design. You only get a notification about it when you pass the treshold for the first time.

Comment: @nicael no. You don't get most notifications once you have linked accounts.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of that. I have not earned that privilege on any SE site before and so haven't previously seen the notification.