# Rep graph & changes don't show effects of migration

Tags: discussion, reputation, migration, reputation-graph

When one's rep on a site drops because a question was migrated to another site, that drop is not reflected at all on the user's rep graph or list of changes to rep; it is as if the question were asked on the second site to begin with; all history events and changes associated with it are listed in the history timeline on the second site.

This isn't really accurate, and could cause some confusion especially if any claims or observations were made about rep levels or privileges, because those statements post-migration appear to have been untrue at the time they were made. (Example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272618/privileges-at-after-1k-not-appearing-in-achievements-dialog).)

Should rep graphs & histories accurately reflect changes to a person's rep *on the site the graph/history is for*?

Please focus discussion on what **would be best** from a UX perspective, instead of arguing "no changes from the status quo should be made because that would require some technical work and that's hard."

Comment: Do you really expect some users are in favor of having inaccurate data?

Comment: @rene: That was the design decision made when building the system, so yes.  Somebody thought it was a good idea that "since giving accurate information would take more work, let's just give users inaccurate information and label it as accurate."  I don't necessarily agree with that decision, but I would be interested in seeing someone defend that viewpoint (which again, is the status quo baked into the system!).  Further, I think I'd be blasted out and closed quickly with "status-bydesign" if I tried calling this unexpected behavior a bug.

Comment: I find your comment kind of disrespectful to the team but that is obviously how this discussion should go. UX-wise having consistent data is preferred but a perfect UX that takes ages to load is maybe correct but also useless. And without the performance trade-off we wouldn't have had the [caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/158100) meme, which would be a real shame.

Comment: @rene no disrespect of *the team* is intended, but I am frustrated by previous attempts to step towards a better functioning, more well-designed site blocked by lines noting e.g. that in UX design decisions "It's not really a matter of what the user expects to happen." I think there are ways this information can be corrected *without* creating a page that takes ages to load or at the very least frame the page so that people don't think inaccurate information is accurate.  I hope one can criticize a *design decision* without that necessarily being taken as an insult or offense to the *team*.